# Is there a simple way to push a sticky post class into wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress, sticky

As far as I know wordpress uses the sticky class only on the frontpages. To use the sticky class as an identifier I like to have it inlisted generally in an archive loop (as for instances category names).

Is there a simple way to push the class into the archive template?

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a tag cloud.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the built-in WordPress [post_class filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters).

Add the below code to your functions.php file (in your theme), and it should add the "sticky" class to posts that are sticky in any archive template.

```
// add sticky class on archive templates
function sticky_archive_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( is_sticky( $post->ID ) ) {
        if ( is_archive() ) {
            $classes[] = 'sticky';
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'sticky_archive_class' );
```

**Important Note:** This relies on the archive template files being properly coded.  If you look at the template, and it does not contain code that looks something like so:

```
<div <?php post_class() ?>>
```

Then the template is *wrong*, and the code will not work, because there's nothing to "filter".

Comment: You are welcome.  If it helped, please upvote and / or accept the answer (click the checkmark and / or up-arrow to the left, by the score)

Comment: That was a very nice solution, thank you very much mate!